# Zend Studio and remote host - best practice

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

Got the following:

1. Zend Studio
2. Zend Framework Project
3. Remote host with FTP and SSH (root access)

Want to:

1. Save directly to remote host.

Currently i'm working on a localhost *AMP server, manually updating the remote through FTP.

Have tried various ways to acomplish the above - unsuccessfull obviously.

Can some one tell me what to do? Studio 5 (pre-eclipse) was so much better for pure 'FTP programming'.

/Philip

Comment: which OS you are using for development?

Comment: Currently WinXP, but sometimes MacOSX - Just need a new Mac :)

Comment: Still no cigar, also i tried ZS 8 Beta.. Crashed and burned!

Comment: Ehh... why have somebody given my question negative? And all the answers has also got a negative !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't use Expandrive. That's what I'm working with now, and it grinds ZSE to a crashing halt. Sometimes, Expandrive just stops working and ZSE thinks the file disappeared, so you have to close everything and anything not saved is lost.

EDIT: One solution that's worked for us is using the SMB protocol, using Windows' SMB compatibility to create a remote drive, and then interacting with your code base that way. Make sure to ignore building large static files or large files you won't be directly editing to further speed up Eclipse when building a project this way.

Comment: That's what i feared.. still no solution to my problem!

Comment: If you don't need some of the advanced features of ZSE, try using Komodo Edit. It has remote editing built right in.

Comment: I'm currently using Samba share at work, on our in-house server. Will try to set it up on the remote host i'm working on.

Answer (score 8):

Currently i'm using remote server support for synchronize my project directly with my i5 server.

It works using ftp or sfpt if you have enabled SSH on your server machine.

It works very well.

1. Before using remote server support you have to set up a connection
   to the server:  go to window menu > open perspective > other >
   remote system explorer
2. set up a connection to your server
3. Return to php develop perspective
4. To add the "support to remote server" to an existing project, click on the project with rigth click > properties > Remote Server Support
5. Flag enable Remote connection properties
6. Set-up all properties and select upload files "on save"

In this way, ZS work locally on the file's project (index, build files ecc) and upload on the server only the .php and .js files.

It can works very well with **svn** suppor too, because it DOESEN'T upload (.svn) files to the server but keeps it local.

Comment: This got me half way there. The missing part is you need to click the Manage button next to the Remote Connection combo box and set the Initial Directory. If you're using FTP you might want to set it to passive mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party utilities:

- [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac) for OSX
- [Netdrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) (commercial) or [FTPDrive](http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html) (free)

to mount FTP/SFTP to drive or folder so you can work as it is locally.

Comment: My problem is ZSE is "building workspace" everytime i save. I remember that i once had some remote_host thingy in ZSE working. But it took forever to save!

But i'll try it out!